# Show precise result of math expression

Tags: math, expression, tcl

I want to do a mathematical operation in Tcl with precise result and e.g. two digits after dot. Example: 1/100 = 0.01. I tried with puts "[format "%.2f" [expr 1/100]]", but that did not work out.

Can someone solve my puzzle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's division `expr` operator only does floating point division if at least one of the arguments is a floating point number. If both are integers, you get integer division.

```
% expr {1/100}
0
% expr {1.0/100}
0.01
% expr {1/double(100)}
0.01
```

As you can see above, the `double` cast-function may help here.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a float value instead of integers to the expression:

```
puts "[format "%.2f" [expr 1/100.0]]"
```

Or...

```
puts "[format "%.2f" [expr 1.0/100]]"
```

Also, it is advised to brace your expressions, for example:

```
puts "[format "%.2f" [expr {1/100.0}]]"
```

Comment: the problem is that I am not passing number but other expressions. Using double works. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @user3518939 Ah, should have said so in your question. You should click the tick outline next to an answer to mark it as the accepted answer and mark your question as solved.